# Prevent direct access of html files under template folder (IBM MFP)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm a little bit of a newbie in MFP so forgive me if this is just a simple question with a simple answer.

Well basically there was a penetration testing on our app and we found out that some of the html files can be directly accessed.

They are under apps > common > templates.

Is there a way to prevent this?

We are using MFP 7.1

What they did was directly inserted the html page path in the url like this:

https://somehost.com/ABCCompany/apps/services/www/ABCCompany/somewebapp/default/app/modules/update-user/view-update-user.html

and with that they were able to view the codes for our html file view-update-user.html

EDIT: I have attached an image.

[image: source codes can be viewed]

Comment: Which platform are you referring to iOS/Android/Windows? How are the files being accessed after it is installed on the device? Please provide complete information.

Comment: windows. It is being accessed like this ---- > https://somehost.com/ABCCompany/apps/services/www/ABCCompany/somewebapp/default/app/modules/update-user/view-update-user.html     so, without even loging in, the update user html template can be accessed outside

Comment: Sounds like your host is not secured...?

Comment: Idan adar: can we just place the html file in some secured folder or something?

Comment: I don't understand the question here... is this a web app or a mobile app?

Comment: It is a web app but built with MFP.

Comment: can it be placed in a secure folder instead? or blocked from direct access

Answer (score 0):

So to me it looks to be either a mobilewebapp or a desktopbrowser app. If that is the case then it works as expected. Anything deployed within the public domain can be accessed externally. You could think of obfuscating/minifying your web content in case it should not be visible externally.

Comment: well its not in the public domain yet. its still in UAT stage. Is there any way to secure the folder containing the html pages?

Comment: By public domain i meant exposed on a web server. Protecting the contents is upto the application to handle it. Here's an example of how its done in [tomcat](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-basic-authentication-with-tomcat.html)

Comment: thats what i want to do but i am not using tomcat. I am using IBM Mobile First 7.0. What I want to know is how to do that in MFP in order for your files not to be directly accessed from the app url, unless you are logged in

Comment: Well thats not in the scope of MFP. MFP is not an application server. Its a runtime hosted on an application server like Liberty or Tomcat. You will need to check on how to protect your resources on the application server you use.

Comment: Sorry I meant in Liberty. Is there a way to secure my html files?

Comment: Not sure if how its done on liberty. You should ask a new question on this and close this.